# How to preserve execution order?

Tags: javascript, loading, yepnope

As for yepnope 1.5, I've read at their page:

> Scripts with the same url won't execute twice, but their callbacks
>   fire in the correct order

but, what about the execution order? is it preserved too? or it will depend on loading finish time?

is the `callback` the only way to to execute js files in the correct order?

Comment: I go to site to see what yepnope is, and it says "yepnope is an asynchronous conditional resource loader". The main thing about async: it's always mean you can't maintain execution order. Callbacks is the heart of technology in this case. I guess yepnope provide any solution for "deffered" calls in case you need to execute some callbacks only when other scripts loaded.

Comment: yea, there might be different js file sizes, or js files that are loaded from different servers bandwidth.. etc such conditions will make it execution randomly, I think I have to use preload! and rely on callback, well?